# Figuring out how to work out n-turple questions?

Tags: math, tuples, system, computer-science

Just as a side note, this isn't asking someone to help with homework it's just a example question in my lecture notes that i'm not grasping and would greatly appreciate if someone could explain to me how exactly to work it out.

It says simply this:

Let G = {3,5,7}. Write down some examples of 4-tuples.

Thank you to anyone who tries to help, this is mathematics to understand a systems unit :)

Answer (score 1):

Your collection G is a set, which is *unordered* and *non-repeating*, containing three elements. You want some 4-tuples, which is an *ordered* collection of *possibly-repeating* elements, and there must be 4 elements.

We show tuples by using parentheses around the collection, while a set like G is written using braces (curly brackets). Some examples of 4-tuples using the elements of G are

```
(3, 3, 3, 3)
(3, 3, 3, 5)
(3, 3, 3, 7)
(3, 3, 5, 3)
...
(7, 7, 7, 5)
(7, 7, 7, 7)
```

That list of mine was in a particular order, called the lexigraphical order. Since there are 4 elements and each element has 3 choices regardless of the other choices, the total number of 4-tuples is

3x3x3x3 = 81

---

As another answer implied, your question is somewhat ambiguous. I assumed that each 4-tuple was to have elements taken from your set G, but your question did not actually say that. It does seem to be implied, however.

Answer (score 0):

A 4-tuple, in math, is any vector populated with 4 objects. An example of a 4-tuple is {1, 5, 3, 7}.

Without more context, I can't use the fact that G = {3, 5, 7}.